# spark.sql.shuffle.partitions - default value

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

As per the doc [https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/support/spark-job-tuning#:~:text=spark.-,sql.,less%20than%20100%20vCPUs%20total.](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/support/spark-job-tuning#:%7E:text=spark.-,sql.,less%20than%20100%20vCPUs%20total.), spark.sql.shuffle.partitions has default value of 200.

Is default value of 200 at each worker node level or overall cluster level? for ex: if we have 1 drive and 5 worker, what would be the default value, is it 200 or 200*5 worker=1000

Comment: default shuffle partitions is 200 for all

Comment: got it, so at cluster level including all nodes put together 200, right?

Comment: yes, 200 is default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (default 200) is at cluster level, regardless of the number of workers.