# determining number of tasks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple spark job doing below steps:

- read 1 day of csv .gz compressed data, size ~540 GB (25425 files)
- basic transforms using withColumn to derive addition columns
- write to delta table , partitioned by year, month and day

  - using partition overwrite mode

I'm running the job on n2d-standard-16 GCP VM using databricks.

- using autoscaling 1 to max 8 nodes
- each machine has 16 cores

Databrciks/GCP by default uses 200 shuffle overall cluster by default. The job has created `5691` tasks. Trying to understand how spark created these many tasks?

My understanding is , number of tasks is equal to number of partitions. In this case shuffle partition is 200, so how spark created 5691 tasks?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

number of tasks is equal to number of partitions
-> yes if in one stage

in this case shuffle partition is 200, so how spark created 5691 tasks
-> check how many jobs and how many stages are there.

Here how spark 3.2.0 create tasks from partition number, you can see spark create one task per partition id:

```scala
    val tasks: Seq[Task[_]] = try {
      val serializedTaskMetrics = closureSerializer.serialize(stage.latestInfo.taskMetrics).array()
      stage match {
        case stage: ShuffleMapStage =>
          stage.pendingPartitions.clear()
          partitionsToCompute.map { id =>
            val locs = taskIdToLocations(id)
            val part = partitions(id)
            stage.pendingPartitions += id
            new ShuffleMapTask(stage.id, stage.latestInfo.attemptNumber,
              taskBinary, part, locs, properties, serializedTaskMetrics, Option(jobId),
              Option(sc.applicationId), sc.applicationAttemptId, stage.rdd.isBarrier())
          }

        case stage: ResultStage =>
          partitionsToCompute.map { id =>
            val p: Int = stage.partitions(id)
            val part = partitions(p)
            val locs = taskIdToLocations(id)
            new ResultTask(stage.id, stage.latestInfo.attemptNumber,
              taskBinary, part, locs, id, properties, serializedTaskMetrics,
              Option(jobId), Option(sc.applicationId), sc.applicationAttemptId,
              stage.rdd.isBarrier())
          }
      }
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) =>
        abortStage(stage, s"Task creation failed: $e\n${Utils.exceptionString(e)}", Some(e))
        runningStages -= stage
        return
    }
```

Comment: is not 200 shuffle partition at cluster level irrespective of number of stages/jobs?

Comment: default value is  200 tasks per stage. a job consist of multiple stages usually. and an application consist of multiple jobs.

Comment: as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77285269/spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-default-value, 200 value is total, not at each stage level.

Comment: You seem to have confused 'stage' with 'worker'.